# How to plot risk ratio within quantiles?

Tags: r, plot

I'm wondering whether there is a simple way to plot risk ratios of a binary outcome within quantiles of another continuous variable. For example,

```
df<-data.frame(y=rbinom(1000,1,0.3),x=rnorm(1000))
```

I would plot p_i(y=1)/(1-p_i) agaist i which is the quantiles((1:4)/5) of x. Does somebody know how to realize it in a easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cut` function to split up `x` based on its quantiles (I just used the 0%, 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% quantiles here, but you can easily specify whichever quantiles you want to the `quantile` function). Then you can use `tapply` to compute the risk ratios for each category.

```
set.seed(144)
df<-data.frame(y=rbinom(1000,1,0.3),x=rnorm(1000))
dat <- tapply(df$y, cut(df$x, quantile(df$x), include.lowest=TRUE),
               function(y) sum(y == 1) / sum(y == 0))
dat
#    [-3.3,-0.742] (-0.742,-0.0597]  (-0.0597,0.764]     (0.764,3.49] 
#        0.4534884        0.4285714        0.3966480        0.4044944
```

You could plot this with something like `qplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(factor(names(dat), levels=names(dat)), dat)
```

[image]